# Regex to get ID of pastebin.com

Tags: php, regex

I need to get the ID part of a pastebin link,

which is setup like http://pastebin.com/{id}, i have tired alot  of different regex i am also using preg_match in php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
preg_match("~http://pastebin.com/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)~", $url, $match);
print_r($match);
```

or

```
$url = "http://pastebin.com/a65d46";
$parsed = parse_url($url);
echo trim($parsed['path'])." is ID you needed";
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of regex, try using [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to extract the path

Answer (score 1):

regex would be overkill for this.

```
$url = "http://pastebin.com/Ugj1eqCN"
$pos = strpos($url,"pastebin.com/");
echo substr($url,$pos+13);
```